# In Java, need program to search for nextInt but not stop if it runs into somethings that's not an Int

Tags: java, loops, int

Here's the piece of the code that's relevant.

> ```
> while (fileDoc.hasNextInt())
>   {
>       int number = fileDoc.nextInt();
>
>       if (number >= max)
>           max = number;
>       if (number <= min)
>           min = number;
>       numbCount++;
>   }
> ```

I need the loop to continue going until it reaches the end of the file, but it only needs to read integers. Currently it'll stop reading the file as soon as it runs into something that's not an int. I'd like some help with a way I could format it to just skip over non-int values.

Apologies if I broke any conventions in this question, this is my first one on this site. Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `next()` method of `Scanner` to skip tokens that aren't valid:

```
while (fileDoc.hasNext()) {
  if (fileDoc.hasNextInt()) {
    int number = fileDoc.nextInt();
    /* Do whatever... */
  } else {
    fileDoc.next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try reading each line as a `String` first and then handle the `Exception` from parsing the `String` into an `int`. You could try something like the following:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file_name.txt")) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(line);
            // your logic here
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```